# (REACTJS) How to only render after async functions complete?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, asynchronous

I have an async function in `ComponentDidMount` that sets a state value.

I also have a function that renders based on the state value.

However, in the `render()`, if i add in the `this.renderSomething()` function, it will use the initial value (null) instead of the value set by the `async` function "function".

This is because the render wont wait for the `async` function to finish.

How do i make it so i can add a function that only renders after you get the value?

```
this.state {
value: null
}

componentDidMount = async () => {
  await function().then(result => {
  this.setState({value = result})
}

renderSomething(){
  if(this.state.value == 1 )
   return (
      <div>
      ... 
      </div>
    )
}

render(){
  return (
   <div>
   {this.renderSomething()}
   </div>
```

Comment: If you are fetching data on the first render it can never be available until *at least* the second render. The best you can do is to conditionally render your UI until the state is populate.

Comment: could u show me how to do so?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if you need to do anything like that. If `state.value` is null on the initial render then `renderSomething` returns nothing. If on some later render the `state.value` is equal to `1` then it returns some JSX. Is there an issue with the current code?

Answer (score 1):

For your case, maybe you could try to move your function `renderSomething()` into `render()` method and change it as variable `let renderSomething` to store JSX component you want to render based on `this.state.value`.

For more, you could see again in React Documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#element-variables

```
this.state {
 value: null
}

async componentDidMount(){
   await function().then(result => this.setState({value = result}))
}

render() {
  const value = this.state.value
  let renderSomething;
  if ( value == 1 ) {
    renderSomething = <div> ... </div>
  } else {
    renderSomething = <div> ... </div>
  }

  return (
   <div>
    {renderSomething}
   </div>
  )
}
```

Hope this could help